# Trace32 Debug in VSCode or Visual Studio

Tags: c, visual-studio, debugging, vscode-debugger, lauterbach

Is there a possibility to debug an embedded C code in VSCode or Visual Studio with an Lauterbach by utilizing the Trace32 Power Debug USB Tools?

Why do I want to do that?

I do not like the GUI provided by Trace32, but it is needed to use the Lauterbach "Power Debug Interface / USB 3"

Maybe there is a way to execute all the necessary commands and get back the line numbers, variable values (classic debug info) via command line. 
By Integrating this into VSCode or Visual Studio one would have an amazing environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TRACE32 can be remote controlled by the following methods:

- Target Communication Framework (TCF), This allows you to control your debugger for the basic tasks via Eclipse. See https://wiki.eclipse.org/TCF
- GDB Remote Serial Protocol
- Lauterbach Remote API

What should you use?

VSCode or Visual Studio do not support TCF, as far as I know. But I guess for your goal of controlling a PowerDebug with a different GUI, I think using Eclipse instead of VSCode and coupling it with TCF is the best solution. Details to TCF in the PDF [app_tcf_setup.pdf](http://www2.lauterbach.com/pdf/app_tcf_setup.pdf) of your TRACE32 installation.

If you insist on VSCode or Visual Studio you can use the "GDB Remote Serial Protocol". TRACE32 is then controlled by Visual Studio like a GDB server. However I would rate the user experience as not as good as with TCF. Details to using TRACE32 as GDB Back-End in the PDF [backend_gdb.pdf](http://www2.lauterbach.com/pdf/backend_gdb.pdf) of your TRACE32 installation. It actually contains a chapter for Visual Studio.

The last option is for those who prefer to dive in really very deeply. The "Lauterbach Remote API" allows you to write you own application to control TRACE32.

Finally I would recommend to become familiar with the TRACE32 GUI instead. The full potential of your debugger can only be used via that GUI, although it might look old fashioned to you. If you want to learn how to use the TRACE32 GUI I would recommend to start with the PDF [training_debugger.pdf](http://www2.lauterbach.com/pdf/training_debugger.pdf) of your TRACE32 installation.